# how to disable external button in angular when form is invalid

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a multiform like this :

```
            <form id="signup-form" name="frm" ng-submit="processForm()" novalidate>
                <!-- our nested state views will be injected here -->
                <div id="form-views" ui-view></div>
            </form>



        <pre>
    {{ formData }}
            <input type="button" value="ذخیره" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="$broadcast('Save')" />
```

how can i disable and enable button if form is invali or vali ?
**the button is out of the form**
Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access to form by it's name, and this object will have a lot of build-in values(see docs): https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form

And `ng-disabled` is directive for, well, disabling:

```
<input ng-disabled="frm.$invalid" type="button" value="ذخیره" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="$broadcast('Save')" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input 
    type="button" 
    ng-disabled="frm.$invalid" 
    value="ذخیره" 
    class="btn btn-primary" 
    ng-click="$broadcast('Save')" />
```

this should work just fine